# Is there an online archive with quality photos of gedolim?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, tzaddikim, rabbis

I'm personally and currently looking for images of Rabbis Shlomo Carlebach & Shlomo Twerski. But I know in the future I'll probably want more for others i.e. R' Wolbe.

A Google search might *provide* images, but as the question suggests 'quality' is the goal i.e. file size, clarity, variety, composition, etc.

Comment: I'd hardly call R' Shlomo Carlebach a gadol. :/

Answer (score 4):

[Gedolim Gallery](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ0Y29-Bgrc4Han26YFlezw) is a Youtube video gallery.

[Gedolim Pics](http://www.gedolimpics.com/#/page/home/) seems to have a variety of Gedolim Pictures available for purchase.

Feel free to look through [the rest of the google search results](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=active&client=opera&hs=3M1&ei=MJ7KWumVCsLSjwSI256wCQ&q=gedolim%20pictures&oq=gedolim%20pictures&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0l2j0i22i30k1l5.8649.9886.0.10057.8.8.0.0.0.0.164.1014.0j8.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.1011....0._qla4QiLZS0).